# Get 10 Most Entered Entries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just wondering if it's possible to retrieve the the most entered entries from the mysql database

It's like this :

ID - Value

Id is auto increment, and value is the text that is being entered, i'd like to have it display the top 10 most entered terms, how could i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT value, COUNT(value) as times
FROM table 
GROUP BY value ORDER BY times DESC LIMIT 0,10;
```

Comment: alright thanks, and then if I want to display this do I do it normally with mysql_fetch_array?

Comment: Yes, and remember to reference COUNT(value) as 'times' ($myFetch['times'])